# Element hide on keypress anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm attempting to make an element slide off the page to the left and a new element slide into the page from the right when the right arrow key is pressed anywhere on the page (not just in a specific input).

jQuery and jQuery UI are implemented. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="box" id="wherebox">
    <h2>Where</h2>
    <br/>
    <div id="wherecontent">
        <input type="text" class="maininputs" name="where" id="where" autofocus="autofocus"/>
        <img src="resources/imgs/right.png" id="wherenext" height="20px" width="50px"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="checkinbox">
    <h2>Check In Date</h2>
    <br />
    <div id="checkincontent">
        <img src="resources/imgs/left.png" id="checkinprev" height="20px" width="50px"/>
        <input type="text" id="checkin" name="checkin" readonly="readonly" class="maininputs"/>
        <img src="resources/imgs/right.png" id="checkinnext" height="20px" width="50px"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('*').bind("rightKey", function(e) {
var $box = $(this).closest('.box'), $next = $box.next();
$box.hide('slide', {
direction : "left"
}, 1000);
$next.delay(750).show('slide', {
direction : "right"
}, 1000);
});
$('*').keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 39) {
$(this).trigger("rightKey");
}
});
```

Anyone know what's missing? Currently it will only work if an input is selected.

Comment: Don't bind on everything `*`, leverage event bubbling.

Comment: BTW, `$('*').bind("rightKey", function(e)` is this a custom event ?

Comment: @elclanrs Can you please elaborate? Only been using Jquery for a few weeks.

Comment: Yup. `$('*').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
   $(this).trigger("rightKey");
  }
 });`

Comment: Check here for more info http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html. Basically attach the event on a higher container or `document` and let event bubbling trigger it. Also FYI `bind` is deprecated, read about `on` to attach events.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost here @elclanrs. Would it be possible for you to quickly whip up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Attach the event like `$(document).on('event', function(e){...})` and that will capture the event on the whole page. Then do your logic inside the callback. `e.target` will tell you the element that captured the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.box').first().show();
$(document).on("rightKey", '.box', function (e) {
    var $box = $(this).closest('.box'),
        $next = $box.next();
    $box.hide('slide', {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    $next.delay(750).show('slide', {
        direction: "right"
    }, 1000);
});
$(document).on('keyup', '.box', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        $(this).trigger("rightKey");
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Mv2At/)